# Send email to commiters from Jenkins email-ext on every build

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I am using Jenkins v1.533, Email-Ext v2.34 and Jenkins Mercurial plugin v1.47, and I want to send emails to the all the mercurial commiters since the last build, for every build.

In *post-build actions*, I added *editable email notification* and added triggers for *success, failure, unstable, still unstable, fixed, still failing* to *recipients, developers, culprits*. The only people who receive the emails are the project recipients. The emails are never sent to the comitters.

```
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/493M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: <*>
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The `<*>` is only the email address I configured in the *project recipient list* (censored here for obvious reasons). How do I get it to send emails to comitters on every build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email-ext does'nt have an option to send mails only to committers.Infact you can use triggers for both Failure and success and trigger mails either to culprits or recipent list or developers.

select either of the three options culprits or recipent list or developers.

Comment: There is an "Upstream Comitters" option (and other options) now. I have listed options for jenkins 2.2 Email-ext 2.42 Triggers and Send To here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39078900/623159 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930314/how-to-configure-a-jenkins-job-to-send-mail-if-a-scm-commit/

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You said that you sent email to developers, do you mean the Send to Committers checkbox?</strike>

From plugin description

> Send to Committers - Check this checkbox to send the email to anyone
>   who checked in code for the last build.  The plugin will generate an
>   email address based on the committer's id and an appended "default
>   email suffix" from Jenkins's global configuration page.  For instance,
>   if a change was committed by someone with an id "first.last", and the
>   default email suffix is "@somewhere.com", then an email will be sent
>   to "first.last@somewhere.com"

Just installed the latest plugin 2.34 (needed to update jenkins as well) and noticed that there was no committers anymore but developers was there instead. Unfortunately, the help for the triggers was broken. So there are only guesses possible.

Check if the way to generate the email address is correct for your scenario and if you have setup  the default email suffix.

Comment: There's no _Committers_ option, only _Developers_: `Send To: Recipients Developers Requestor Culprits` so I figured that _Developers_ was the old _Committers_ label changed.

Comment: You are right :( - Did you check, whether you have set the default email suffix?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have set up the default email suffix as well. I still get the list of recipients as empty. I use Git plugin version 2.4.0. Any other leads on this?